# Selecting rows with dates before a given date using pandasql

Tags: pandas, pandasql

I have this data frame, where id is an `int64`, and date is `datetime64[ns]`:

```
         id                        date
0   1811302  2017-03-08 00:00:00.000000
1     16095  2013-03-12 00:00:00.000000
2     16095  2017-09-15 00:00:00.000000
..      ...                         ...
74  1111806  2017-09-15 00:00:00.000000
75   482254  2013-01-01 00:00:00.000000
76   482254  2015-12-16 00:00:00.000000
```

In reality, my data frame has more than a million number of rows.

Now, using pandasql, how do I extract rows before a given date, say before 2017-09-11?

I tried:

```
sqlcode = 'SELECT id, date from df where strftime("%Y-%m-%d", date) < {}'.format("2017-09-11")
ps.sqldf(sqlcode,locals())
```

Which returns nothing:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [id, date]
Index: []
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, it turns out the quotes around the curly brackets are important:

```
sqlcode = 'SELECT id, date from df where strftime("%Y-%m-%d", date) < "{}"'.format("2017-09-11")
ps.sqldf(sqlcode,locals())
```